# Opencart confirmation email

Tags: opencart

I'm not receiving confirmation on opencart version  2.1.0.1.

The image of the mail tab in settings is given below. [opencart email page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yDxGX.jpg)

Can anyone please help me on this ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found out the answer.

You'll have to turn less secure apps from this url https://www.google.com/settings/security/lesssecureapps for gmail

Answer (score 0):

When using SMTP settings with Gmail and Opencart use the following settings:

```
 - Mail Protocol : SMTP
 - Mail Parameters : (blank) 
 - SMTP Host : ssl://smtp.gmail.com 
 - SMTP Username : <youremail>@gmail.com  
 - SMTP Password : <your password>
 - SMTP Port : 465
 - SMTP Timeout : 5
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this method.
Goto public_html/system/library/mail.php
find this code:

```
$header .= 'From: ' . '=?UTF-8?B?' . base64_encode($this->sender) . '?=' . ' <' . $this->from . '>' . $this->newline;
$header .= 'Reply-To: ' . '=?UTF-8?B?' . base64_encode($this->sender) . '?=' . ' <' . $this->from . '>' . $this->newline;
```

replace with this code:

```
//$header .= 'From: =?UTF-8?B?' . base64_encode($this->sender) . '?=' . ' <' . $this->from . '>' . $this->newline;
$header .= 'From: emil@youremailid.com' . $this->newline;

if (!$this->reply_to) {
            $header .= 'Reply-To: =?UTF-8?B?' . base64_encode($this->sender) . '?=' . ' <' . $this->from . '>' . $this->newline;
} else {
            $header .= 'Reply-To: =?UTF-8?B?' . base64_encode($this->reply_to) . '?=' . ' <' . $this->from . '>' . $this->newline;
}
```

take backup of the file is advised.